How to Securely Redirect to a Dynamic Logout URL in Vue.js Without Causing an Open Redirect Vulnerability?
I'm working on a Vue.js application where we need to securely redirect users to a logout URL. This URL is dynamically set through environment variables (process.env.VUE_APP_LOGOUT), which changes based on the environment (e.g., development, staging, production).
logout() {
  window.location.href = process.env.VUE_APP_LOGOUT;
}

The Problem
Using a dynamic URL for redirection introduces an Open Redirect vulnerability, which can be exploited in phishing attacks if the URL is not properly validated. I want to ensure that this redirection only points to approved domains and does not expose our application to security risks.
Question
What is the best way to securely handle dynamic URL redirection in Vue.js for logout, without exposing the app to open redirect vulnerabilities? Is it secure to store URLs in an array within the project and validate them from there? Any recommended practices or security-focused solutions would be greatly appreciated!

It would only be an open redirect vulnerability to begin with, if I as an attacker could manipulate that value for a user of your app. "This URL is dynamically set through environment variables" - and how would I manipulate those from the outside ...?

If you store these in a file on the server, then you need to avoid any unacceptable access to it:

don't version your environment files, so 1. devs will not necessarily be entrusted with production data, 2. you can differentiate between values on different settings (prod, staging, experimental, etc.)
make sure that wherever these files are located, the access rights are properly defined

It is also advisable to build a token for the logout to be passed to that depends on the user and the time which will validate the logout process. The reason for this is that no matter how secure your file is, whoever has access to the router of the network your user operates at will be able to figure out these URLs. So you will need some validation beyond the actual value of the logout URL.

Environment files are stored within the frontend project and can be modified by developers with access rights. Unfortunately, I can't change this setup at the moment. Given this situation, what should I do?

@Caner it depends on whether you are worried about devs with access rights being able to change them. If not, then all good. If yes, then we need to identify what specific attributes you are worried about. Also, anyone with access rights can manipulate a file. So if you worry about a particular dev, then you can revoke this right for him/her

In fact, Fortify gives a warning on this: Allowing unvalidated input to control the URL used in a redirect can aid phishing attacks.

@Caner how are your devs changing this? Are they ssh-ing to the server?

They access the codes via VPN.

@Caner are you worried about your devs being able to access it?

Actually yes we are worried.

@Caner " Allowing unvalidated input" - there is no input in your case and so there is no problem

@Caner I see. Have you considered removing access right from devs whom you are worried about?

Maybe fortify is returning incorrectly.
